# .NET MVC Weird and meaningless runtime error messages from server

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I've recently changed the custom errors mode to Off for my .NET MVC web application and surprised by the message content.

Here is an example:

> �Z�o�H�}��fY]�Ձ�n h�$�
>   ]7Q�:m�tl��l��x�����@>�^o#%�����~g���O�'7��<#C�{��$�:C�nrm�StOD乄E������JED��!���'�=*����U���H|P���#�����z�U��`����c�)%�L©G��q
>   �*Gp\��U�#F́��)�rzy�&x���|�#@�O}�MZ�w
>   ]�i�mF��C��B�ԋ�B�h���#���p,�������?��?�#~MyX��A�QY$��A�>�p��%���fA\R���=�$�:e=l�  �'����4��PNlL!�Y��Q8W`:+��6`{�ڜٕas9�!8��>�a�evx�7Z�o*���F��W#{?��OT'��h������
>   �=��s����^�{� ��R���Ć7��]�j���כ�K`o�:��S�@�>N�V��j��<��wc�ã�����@bl~;]����L   �"諊���o���
>   w��a�ͯH�@�uO-�����V�q���=��ۑc;:&o
>   �)��E9�J�3Sr����nS�=|#Ph��%� �N77�VD�
>   }�g���d�Hz�̬�r���$��2K�6���#�J+�L�����4��d-;��'ש����k�&\�ԡ�sv�M���}{[?���+#O:���a�F�8v�Va��j�֫����q���f�P�;����B���w��I��j!���F��\������hY����;w�{��X�:�&L����fY4or���F0��1�YY/Vc������S�NN��+l�|���� w�/��b���
>   L�Ne�TR-/��9Q�(��.���s�W�+����_�F�fgG#q~�1a���q�����G5��g�k�s�̯�v��tS��o�E��n6�x���S��j�[�    ����zN�lrx33�S�8Ӈ��]�jd�.ǯS�6s|:_�:�hon�����ګ/��ݏ)�L�zK����r��s�Λ
>   ۥ��U��D//x�2j�V�ߩ��Gpޢi��dژBK=��+�-Eɩ���ѾJ@Φ�ĵ�
>   -�HK���ř����/����9s Y�W�/�\�k!<�|������@�A��7ob^����)����@Xl�Z38�w    _��uױ��0h�e���+b�vvC�跬��w$Y�jX�^�W�����LZyd���Ɗ��fS��sY3���s����~*�H.�����Fa����X�Z!9�S��ݘ�=��X��y��5B���X#�[�5ֹ������>��ج_�ob���㥥�·�vG����r��Ύ/�݄  ye��d�����TpE�z}���!!�x�'�;���.�u���U3�쌠vz��eg�y��}���©�`g��>�  z��v}�"�xY��ϻc��?<�/?��FV���dpH��H�]��1m{�)C�2�������&��M?�P*uz�f���Z���
>   M3���x���e�C#|�26���l�/�)A¡�H[�ӯ��f����hnՉB%|Cw��..��BY����*s���/��|�"�L�*(���$��vR���    �C���Uh�*�

Do anyone has any idea for this behavior?

My globalization settings are:

```
  <globalization uiCulture="en-US" />
```

Comment: Looks like a binary content!  May be a compress response of the error message from server that was not interpreted by the browser for some reason?  Can you use Fiddler or the browsers developer tools to check out the response header and body?

Comment: Check if the "O" is in uppercase in your web.config file. This is because "Off" is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake. I did implement a CustomAttribute for compression which implements the section below:

```
    if (encodingsAccepted.Contains("deflate"))
    {
        response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
        response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
    }
    else if (encodingsAccepted.Contains("gzip"))
    {
        response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
        response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
    }
```

I did remove it in case of error and it is working without problem. Thank you @Phil B for your comment which helped me to solve it out!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before some days. And i solved it by following the steps below:
In machine.config file there should be an entry:

```
<deployment retail="true" />
```

This seems to override any other customError settings that you have specified in a web.config file, so change the above setting to:

```
<deployment retail="false" />
```

Hope this helps you save some time.

Comment: Also another possibility is that you should check if  the "O" is in uppercase in your web.config file. This is because "Off" is case-sensitive.